# MySQL row declarations?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, zend-framework

What do these mean in MySQL? I'm using MySQL workbench and I see I can specify a new column as these... (I noted my guesses)

- PK – (primary key)
- NN – (non null)
- BIN – (binary?)
- UN – (Unicode?)
- ZF- (???)
- AI – (autoincrement?)

Is AI exactly like an Identity specification in MSSQL? (Can I insert a record without specifying the value and it will insert the next available int?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ZF` is probably `ZEROFILL`:

```
CREATE TABLE zf (id INT(5) ZEROFILL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);

INSERT
INTO    zf
VALUES  (1);

SELECT  *
FROM    zf;

--
00001
```

`UN` is not `UNICODE`, but `UNSIGNED` (`ZEROFILL` implies it)

Answer (score 1):

NN means not null,

Is AI exactly like an Identity specification in MSSQL? (Can I insert a record without specifying the value and it will insert the next available int?)

Yes you can insert that way.